# AWS API gateway configure vpc endpoint id from different region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc, vpc

### *Current Scenario*

Currently, we are having our AWS API gateway of type PRIVATE in EU-central-1. if we try to configure VPC endpoint from region in ap-southeast-1
we are getting error like 
*is not valid vpc endpoint id*
but when we try to configure it from same region it works well.
not sure how to resolve this error

Comment: Cross-region is not supported - you cannot access an API in region1 from a VPC endpoint in region2 directly. If you need to do that, peer the two VPCs of different regions and then try access it.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to one service from VPC A to another in VPC B you can use followin Amazon VPC-to-Amazon VPC Connectivity Options - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/aws-vpc-connectivity-options/amazon-vpc-to-amazon-vpc-connectivity-options.html
Each one has its own advantages and limitations.
AWS private linkis one of these options. Attaching one image from offical doc here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/aws-vpc-connectivity-options/aws-privatelink.html

[image: AWS Private Link]

Here is the link for VPC endpoint and supported service - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html

Comment: thanks for your inputs. we are trying to avoid using VPC peering. as VPC peering is not good option if you want your service to be used by multiple clients they don't want to expose or provide their vpc details.

Comment: Did you try using VPC endpoint (AWS PrivateLink) which I have shared in the second link, it supports Amazon API gateway. Updating my answer with one more link, hope that answers

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, for your use case, it is necessary to use a PrivateLink with VpcPeering:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/aws-privatelink/use-case-examples.html#inter-region-endpoint-services

I think this will help you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35816889)